# MySQL query never end

Tags: mysql

Below query execute within 0.003 seconds.

```
SELECT * FROM cs.cs_15 where instr like '%X_T%' and end_time>'2016-09-22' LIMIT 0, 1000
```

But when running following query, it just keep running without end:

```
SELECT * FROM cs.cs_15 where instr like '%X_T%' limit 1
```

Anyone have idea why?

Table Structure:

```
    +------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
    | Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
    +------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
    | instr      | varchar(45) | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
    | start_time | timestamp   | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
    | end_time   | timestamp   | NO   | PRI | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
    | a          | float       | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
    | b          | float       | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
    | c          | float       | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
    | d          | float       | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
    | e          | float       | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
    | f          | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
    +------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

Index:

```
+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table           | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| cs_15           |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | instr       | A         |      172410 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| cs_15           |          0 | PRIMARY    |            2 | end_time    | A         |    21551290 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| cs_15           |          0 | unique_idx |            1 | end_time    | A         |     3078755 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| cs_15           |          0 | unique_idx |            2 | instr       | A         |    21551290 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: How many records does `cs_15` table has. Check if `instr` column in `cs_15` table has [indexing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3568214/377342) enabled to it.

Comment: Since there is no `order by` specified then it is very likely that the arbitrary ordering of records produces no matches for millions of records. If the `instr` field is a text field with lots of text per row then the slowdown is exacerbated. Unless you provide the table structure details then it will be very hard to pinpoint your exact issue.

Comment: added more detail.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE cs_15`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

Answer (score 1):

You have `UNIQUE(end_time, instr)`, correct?  Then the fast query (`SELECT * FROM cs.cs_15 where instr like '%X_T%' and end_time>'2016-09-22' LIMIT 0, 1000`) will be performed this way.  (Confirm it by doing `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.)

1. Reach into that index at '2016-09-22'.
2. Scan forward, looking for `instr like '%X_T%'`
3. peel off the first 1000 that match.

Note: Apparently many of the rows have `X_T`, so the query ends quickly.

The slow query (`SELECT * FROM cs.cs_15 where instr like '%X_T%' limit 1`) will be performed this way.  (Confirm it by doing `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.)

1. No index is useful, so scan the entire table, looking for 1 row with `instr like '%X_T%'`.

Note: Apparently there is no such row *early* in the table.  That is, old end_times never had `X_T`.

There is not good way to speed up the slow query.  The leading wildcard in the `LIKE` make it useless to index that column.

Comment: They might get some improvement if they add an index on `instr` alone. Assuming an average length of around 20 bytes for each varchar columns, the average row size will be about 100 bytes while the average index row size, for that index, will be about 30. So, instead of a full table scan, it will do a full index scan to find 1 row. So, it would get about a 3x efficiency speedup, if my calcs are right. (not a super improvement but not bad either.) Do you agree?

Comment: I don't think there is an id, the primary key is `(instr, end_time)`

Comment: (oops - deleting my comment about lazy eval.)